# Links to root don't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some divs that I have appended using Jquery.  They are links that navigate to other pages in my site.  My site is hosted on my computer and are not hosted online.  I am trying to prepare the files to be transferred to my domain, but the links don't seem to work if they aren't the full link to exactly where the files are in the computer.

Here's what the jquery looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#work').hover(function () {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(/Users/gcp0001/Desktop/Home/work.png)')
    });

});
```

That's what it takes to make the link work.  I can't just type in:

```
 ...'url(Home/work.png)'
```

Why can't I do this?  What do I have to do to ensure that the links work when I upload the files to the domain?

Comment: whats the folder structure?

Comment: What is the webroot directory?

Comment: Are you using a web server on your machine to host the files, or is it plain HTML running in your browser?

Comment: Are you running a local webserver, or are you just using `file:///` URLs?

Comment: Just a little note: don't use divs for linking purpose. Use <a> with "display:block".

Comment: Do you have your base defined? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: If you want to simulate a server environment I suggest you use Python's SimpleHTTPServer - [here's a short blog post explaining it](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python). It's very lightweight and simply serves up files so that your browser can use server security rules, not local file ones. It comes with Python, doesn't need to be installed, is tiny and lightweight, and can be started in a few seconds. It's excellent. I use it myself and I strongly recommend you do as well.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea and the tutorials I have read so far seem to describe a pretty simple operation, but I have no clue how to use python.  They keep referring to a terminal, but I don't know if they are referring to the terminal on my machine or if there's one that comes with python.  Yes, this sounds like it is probably really simple if you know python already, but this is really confusing to approach having no prior knowledge.

Comment: ^^^^^^I'm not sure how to answer the questions about what the folder structure is.  There's a folder on my desktop called 'Home', there's one set of folders below that, then one or two of those folders contains another folder full of images.  That's it.  I'm building and testing the site from my computer and it seems to require me to have the full link to exactly where the file is on my machine rather than a simple link to the root.

Comment: ^^^When I type in the code from that blog post into the shell that I finally found, it tells me that there's a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

> What do I have to do to ensure that the links work when I upload the
>   files to the domain?

Install Apache (WWW server) on your local computer and configure it so you can run (and test) you code using `http://localhost` address.

Comment: Apache is immense overkill for these purposes.